# What is the benefit using different type when creating an object in java

Tags: java

What is the benefit using different type when creating an object in java?

If i have 2 classes:

```
public class Animal {

    public Animal() {
    }

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Moving...");
    }
}


public class Bird extends Animal {

    public Bird() {
    }

    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("Flying...");
    }
}
```

When i should use:

```
Animal bird1 = new Bird();
```

and

```
Bird bird2 = new Bird();
```

I still can not understand if Bird extends Animal, why using Animal as variable type?

Comment: When `bird1` will be used in a context where you don't care whether it's a `Bird` or a `Reptile`

Comment: J. Doem this is the same like asking:" why build a foundation when you build a house". In Animal you put everything that is shared among all types of Animals, the specifications for each type of Animal, you put in the subclasses.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947

Comment: Well there could be use case where you iterate through a list of Animals and call the move method on the returned object.

Comment: It is related to concept of dynamic polymorphism or method overriding in oop.